# building an RPM package from NodeJS project packaged as a binary

Tags: node.js, binaryfiles, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to package a `NodeJS` project as an RPM, I was initially using `speculate` package from `npm` to create the build directory structure, generate `tar` archive, and create a spec file. This keeps breaking on me.

To avoid dependencies issues I'm packaging the node project as a binary executable using `pkg`.

I'm using `docker` with `centos` to build an RPM, I've manually created the build skeleton, `/root/rpmbuild/RPMS`, `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES`, etc... I've put the packaged binary into `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES`.

I've removed the build steps from the `menlolab-runner.spec` it looks as follows:

```
%define name menlolab-runner
%define version 0.2.6
%define release 1

Name: %{name}
Version: %{version}
Release: %{release}
Summary: menlolab-runner

Group: Installation Script
License: MIT
Source: runner
AutoReqProv: no

%description
The agent deployed on private and public infrastructure to manage tasks.

%global debug_package %{nil}

%prep

%build

%pre
getent group menlolab-runner >/dev/null || groupadd -r menlolab-runner
getent passwd menlolab-runner >/dev/null || useradd -r -g menlolab-runner -G menlolab-runner -d / -s /sbin/nologin -c "menlolab-runner" menlolab-runner

%install
cp -r /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/runner /usr/bin/menlolab-runner

%post
cp /runner/rpm-build/menlolab-runner.service /etc/systemd/system/
systemctl enable /usr/lib/menlolab-runner/menlolab-runner.service
chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/menlolab-runner
mkdir -p '/etc/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/etc/menlolab-runner'
chmod 700 '/etc/menlolab-runner'
mkdir -p '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/'
mkdir -p '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/jobs/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/jobs/'
mkdir -p '/var/log/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/log/menlolab-runner/'
mkdir -p '/var/cache/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/cache/menlolab-runner/'
groupadd docker
usermod -aG docker menlolab-runner

%clean

%files
%defattr(644, menlolab-runner, menlolab-runner, 755)
/usr/lib/menlolab-runner
/var/log/menlolab-runner
```

My `systemd` service file is bellow:

```
[Unit]
Description=The agent deployed on private and public infrastructure to manage tasks.
After=network.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start
WorkingDirectory=/usr/lib/menlolab-runner
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=menlolab-runner
User=menlolab-runner
Group=menlolab-runner

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To start the build process `rpmbuild -bb SPECS/menlolab-runner.spec` is used.

I keep getting the following errors:

```
RPM build errors:
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/menlolab-runner-0.2.6-1.x86_64/usr/lib/menlolab-runner
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/menlolab-runner-0.2.6-1.x86_64/var/log/menlolab-runner
```

I'm not sure what's causing them as I'm skipping the `%build` section is the spec file. The entire output of the `rpmbuild` can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/DhXfzrJ3)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `%files` section was causing issues removing the last two lines `/usr/lib/menlolab-runner` and `/var/log/menlolab-runner` has resolved the issue.

The final version of the `spec` file looks as follows:

```
%define name menlolab-runner
%define version 0.2.6
%define release 1

Name: %{name}
Version: %{version}
Release: %{release}
Summary: menlolab-runner

Group: Installation Script
License: MIT
Source: runner
AutoReqProv: no

%description
The agent deployed on private and public infrastructure to manage tasks.

%global debug_package %{nil}

%prep

%build

%pre
getent group menlolab-runner >/dev/null || groupadd -r menlolab-runner
getent passwd menlolab-runner >/dev/null || useradd -r -g menlolab-runner -G menlolab-runner -d / -s /sbin/nologin -c "menlolab-runner" menlolab-runner

%install
cp -r /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/runner /usr/bin/menlolab-runner

%post
cp /runner/rpm-build/menlolab-runner.service /etc/systemd/system/
systemctl enable /usr/lib/menlolab-runner/menlolab-runner.service
chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/menlolab-runner
mkdir -p '/etc/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/etc/menlolab-runner'
chmod 700 '/etc/menlolab-runner'
mkdir -p '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/'
mkdir -p '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/jobs/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/jobs/'
mkdir -p '/var/log/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/log/menlolab-runner/'
mkdir -p '/var/cache/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/cache/menlolab-runner/'
groupadd docker
usermod -aG docker menlolab-runner

%clean

%files
%defattr(644, menlolab-runner, menlolab-runner, 755)
```